# Set group of directory to name of directory

Tags: bash, terminal, find, chgrp

I have a bunch of folders I would like to find and change the group to the directory name.

```
/SchoolA/
/SchoolB/
......
/SchoolZZZ/
```

I can't figure it out - but would like something like:

```
find . -type d -exec chgrp {} {} \;
```

I get illegal group name because that includes ./ on the group. Anyway to eliminate the ./

Needs to be something like

```
find . -type d -exec chgrp NODOTSLASH({}) {} \;
```

****EDIT****

I am closer with the help of the posts below - but it still prints the "." directory. How do I get rid of that?

```
find . \( ! -path '^.*' \)  -type d -maxdepth 1 | sed -e 's/\.\///g' | awk '{print "\x22"$0"\x22","\x22"$0"\x22"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type d | sed -e 's/\.\///g' | awk '{print $1, $1}' | xargs chgrp
```

A more adhoc approach to avoid dots `.`

```
find . -type d | sed -e 's/\.\///g' -e 's/\./avoid/g' | grep -v avoid | awk '{print $1"\t"$1}' | xargs chgrp
```

The above also applies tab space between the two words.

Comment: This is very close - however, spaces (which I didn't specify would be in there) do not work correctly. However - I did modify some to try to get the correct result - but still not quite right. Thanks for you help so far! See original post for how I modified. Thanks again!

Comment: Added more info to my answer... This should solve the `dot` problem. I have tested it on my Mac, and it seems to be working...

Comment: Great - that fixed the . issue. I also used $0 instead of $1 and surrounded it with quotes as the group/folder names I have did have spaces. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop with formatting:

```
find . -type d -printf '%f\t%p\n' | while IFS=$'\t' read A B; do chgrp "$A" "$B"; done
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work on my Mac - says -printf: unknown primary or operator.